# Delphi RTTI Set Value by attribute value

Tags: delphi, attributes, rtti

I have class like this

```
TuserClass = class
private
 FUtilisateurCode: string; 
 FUtilisateurCle: string;
public
 procedure SetCodeInt(ACode: string; AValue: string);   
published
 [CodeInt('2800')]
 property UtilisateurCode: String read FUtilisateurCode write FUtilisateurCode;
 [CodeInt('2801')]
 property UtilisateurCle: String read FUtilisateurCle write FUtilisateurCle;
end;

procedure TuserClass.SetCodeInt(ACode: string; AValue: string); 
begin
  // what I want to is making this by RTTI to set good value to good CodeInt
  if ACode = '2800' then FutilisateurCode := AValue
  else if ACode = '2801' then FUtilisateurCle := AValue;
end;
```

I want to use my SetCodeInt procedure to fill my property value but I have problem. 
What I have to do ?

Comment: It would be better if you posted the real code. It is somewhat hard to work out what `SetCodeInt` is all about. Not least because you never call it. You need to fix your question because it currently requires us to read your mind. Probably somebody will be able to do that but we should not have to.

Comment: I update my question to explicit what I want to make

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a custom attribute class:

```
type
  CodeIntAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  private
    FValue: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer);
    property Value: Integer read FValue;
  end;
....
constructor CodeIntAttribute.Create(AValue: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FValue := AValue;
end;
```

I've chosen to make the value an integer which seems more appropriate than a string.

Then you define the properties like this:

```
[CodeInt(2800)]
property UtilisateurCode: string read FUtilisateurCode write FUtilisateurCode;
[CodeInt(2801)]
property UtilisateurCle: string read FUtilisateurCle write FUtilisateurCle;
```

Finally the implementation of `SetCodeInt` is:

```
procedure TUserClass.SetCodeInt(ACode: Integer; AValue: string);
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  attr: TCustomAttribute;
  codeattr: CodeIntAttribute;
begin
  typ := ctx.GetType(ClassType);
  for prop in typ.GetProperties do
    for attr in prop.GetAttributes do
      if attr is CodeIntAttribute then
        if CodeIntAttribute(attr).Value=ACode then
        begin
          prop.SetValue(Self, TValue.From(AValue));
          exit;
        end;
  raise Exception.CreateFmt('Property with code %d not found.', [ACode]);
end;
```

Comment: If you change `ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TUserClass))` to `ctx.GetType(ClassType)` then this code will also work for classes that derive from `TUserClass`, otherwise it is specific to `TUserClass` only.

Comment: @Remy Thank you. I would have been very happy for you to make such an obvious improvement as an edit, btw.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I only edit people's answers when there is good reason to do so. In this case, there is no indication that `TUserClass` is ever derived from. I was merely pointing out a possible tweak, not a requirement.